# Python plot monthlywise data between two variables

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to plot the data between two variables. In that I want to plot monthly data using a special color.

My code and expectedoutput:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df
             A     B
2019-01-01   10   20
2019-01-02   20   30
2019-02-01   10   15
2019-02-02   20   40
2019-03-01   12   32
2019-03-02   5    14

plt.plot(df['A'],df['B'])
plt.show()
```

My current plot plots all the data as usual but I am expecting something different as given below. 
My expected output:

[image]
2019-03-01   10   20

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
markers = 'dsxo'
months = pd.to_datetime(df.index).to_period('M')

for i, (k,d) in enumerate(df.groupby(months) ):
    plt.plot(d['A'],d['B'], label=k, marker=markers[i])

plt.legend()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This looks good. I have two years data actually. So, 24 markers. how to get this done in that case?

Comment: When I run your code I get this error: `AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'to_period'`

Comment: Here's a [link](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/markers_api.html) for list of markers. Also see update for string index.

Comment: This worked. How do I remove the connecting lines and have only the markers?

Comment: Replace `plot` with `scatter`.

Comment: Yes. This worked. Also, I ran into another issue. Here is the code `     `plt.scatter(df['POA'],df['TB1'], label=k, marker=valid_markers[i],markerfacecolor='none')`. This gives `AttributeError: Unknown property markerfacecolor`

Comment: Just remove `makerfacecolor`? `scatter` does not have that

Answer (score 1):

Check this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

df['Month'] = df.index.map(lambda x: x[:-3])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (6, 6))
for month in df['Month'].unique():
    ax.plot(df[df['Month'] == month]['A'],
            df[df['Month'] == month]['B'],
            label = month)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

that gives this graph:

[image]